# this pointer cannot be aliased in a constructor:

Tags: c++, class, c++11, language-lawyer, this

I am learning about inheritance in C++. And i came across the following [statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this):

> In other words, the this pointer cannot be aliased in a constructor:

```
extern struct D d;
struct D
{
    D(int a) : a(a), b(d.a) {} // b(a) or b(this->a) would be correct
    int a, b;
};
D d = D(1);   // because b(d.a) did not obtain a through this, d.b is now unspecified
```

The above example is from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this).

My **first question** is that it is written that "`this` cannot be aliased in a ctor" but then in the example above, they've written in the comment "`b(this->a)` would be correct". This seems to be a contradiction to me because when they said that `this` cannot be aliased in a ctor i understood that "`this` cannot be **used** in a ctor". But then why are they saying that writing `b(this->a)` would be correct if `this` cannot be used/aliased in a ctor. Isn't the initializer list considered "in a ctor"?

---

Now lets look at a custom example:

```
struct Name 
{
    private: 
        int x = 0;
  Name(int n )
  {
     this->x = 4;  //is the use of "this" well-defined here?
  }
};
```

My **second question** is that is the use of the expression `this->x` inside the converting constructor shown above well-defined? I mean since according the quote at the beginning of my question `this` can't be aliased in a ctor, so this shouldn't be valid.

Comment: You misunderstood when you understood that it meant "used". Aliasing is when two or more things refer to the same object, such as `*this` and `d` in the example.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ok this makes some sense.

Comment: The problem is not using `this` in a constructor, but in using `d.a` in the constructor of `d`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is meant is that during the construction of a class object any access to the object's non-static data members should happen through a pointer/glvalue obtained directly or indirectly from `this` of the constructor. Otherwise the value read by such an access is unspecified.

So `this->a` is always fine, as is simply `a` which is implicitly the same as `this->a`.

It is also ok to copy the pointer `this` and access members through that, e.g.

```
auto p = this;
b = p->a;
```

or to store a reference to the object:

```
auto& r = *this;
b = r.a;
```

But in the example given at the beginning, `d` is the same object as `this` points to. In other words the name `d` and `*this` are aliases for the same object. It is not allowed to use this other alias `d` to access non-static data members of the class while it is under construction because `d` was not obtained from `this`. Or to be more precise, it is unspecified what value such an access will read. So `b(d.a)` may or may not initialize the `b` member to the same value as `a`.

See [[class.cdtor]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.cdtor#2).

Comment: @Anya `this` is the same in a constructor as usual in a non-static member function. It always refers to the object under construction in a constructor.

Comment: @Anya Feel free to ask another question for it, but I think I recently answered another of your questions clarifying that `this` is not the same as the implicit object parameter. So maybe your question should really be whether a constructor has an implicit object parameter.